# Swift delegate and protocol method not calling in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

I have parsing the `JSON` values in `UITableView` using MVC pattern, For that, I have created a separate `UITableView` swift class, Model class, and `UIViewController` class as well.

I can able to parse the JSON values into the table view. But the problem is I can't able to pass the selected tableView cell values to my controller using the delegate method

Here my code is

**UIVIewController :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,contactSelectionDelegate {
var contactArray = [Address]()
@IBOutlet weak var userTable: UserTable!
let user = UserTable()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    user.userdelegate? = self
    if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
        print("Yes! Network connection is available")
        APIManager.sharedInstance.fetchUserDetails(urlString: FETCH_USER_DETAIL_URL, userCount: ["offset":1]) { connectionResult in

            switch connectionResult {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    self.contactArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([Address].self, from: data)

                    print(self.contactArray.count)
                    print(self.contactArray[0].Name)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(self.contactArray)
                        self.userTable.dataSourceArray=self.contactArray
                        self.userTable.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                catch let errorValue {
                    print(errorValue)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        print("No network connection")
    }
}

func selectedUserContact(name: String, email: String, phone: String) {
    print("Delegate Called")
    let userdetailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserContactDetailPage") as! UserContactDetailPage
    userdetailVC.name = name
    userdetailVC.email = email
    userdetailVC.phone = phone
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userdetailVC, animated: true)
} }
```

**UITableView :**

```
protocol contactSelectionDelegate: class{
func selectedUserContact(name: String ,email: String ,phone: String)
}

class UserTable: UITableView ,UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDataSource  {


var dataSourceArray  =   [Address]()
weak var userdelegate: contactSelectionDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.delegate=self
    self.dataSource=self
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataSourceArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UserCell   =   tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    if self.dataSourceArray.count>0 {
        let myUser  =   self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLbl.text  =   myUser.Name
        cell.emailLbl.text  =   myUser.Email
        cell.phoneLbl.text =   myUser.Phone
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myUser  =   self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]
    print(myUser.Name)
    print(myUser.Email)
    print(myUser.Phone)
     userdelegate?.selectedUserContact(name: myUser.Name, email: myUser.Email, phone: myUser.Phone)
}}
```

Here when I click table on the `tableView` cell `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method called but `selectedUserContact` not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood the purpose of delegating here. The idea is that your table view is only responsible for drawing a table, it shouldn't be responsible for maintaining any of the data that it's displaying. This allows you to cleanly design your code using the Model-View-Controller (MVC) paradigm. Delegation allows your controllers to pass model information to the views without breaking MVC.

In your example: `Address` is the model, the table view is the view, and your view controller is the controller. So you want your controller to conform to the table view's delegate/data source protocols so that it can feed the data to it correctly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var contactArray = [Address]()
    @IBOutlet weak var userTable: UserTable!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
            print("Yes! Network connection is available")
            APIManager.sharedInstance.fetchUserDetails(urlString: FETCH_USER_DETAIL_URL, userCount: ["offset":1]) { connectionResult in

                switch connectionResult {
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        self.contactArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([Address].self, from: data)

                        print(self.contactArray.count)
                        print(self.contactArray[0].Name)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print(self.contactArray)
                            self.userTable.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    catch let errorValue {
                        print(errorValue)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            print("No network connection")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.contactArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UserCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
        let myUser = self.contactArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLbl.text = myUser.Name
        cell.emailLbl.text = myUser.Email
        cell.phoneLbl.text = myUser.Phone
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let myUser = self.contactArray[indexPath.row]
        print(myUser.Name)
        print(myUser.Email)
        print(myUser.Phone)
        selectedUserContact(name: myUser.Name, email: myUser.Email, phone: myUser.Phone)
    }

    // MARK: -

    func selectedUserContact(name: String, email: String, phone: String) {
        print("Delegate Called")
        let userdetailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserContactDetailPage") as! UserContactDetailPage
        userdetailVC.name = name
        userdetailVC.email = email
        userdetailVC.phone = phone
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userdetailVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just want to add that you need to make sure in your storyboard that you set `ViewController` as the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the table view. Then you can remove all the code that you've written in the `UserTable` class. If anything you don't need it at all and your table view can be a simple `UITableView`. I almost never create subclasses of it, since you can normally do everything through the delegation and `UITableViewCell` subclasses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply , have one doubt is it possible to pass values between view to controller using delegate protocol?

Comment: Sure, if you want.

Comment: that's what am trying to pass the did select values to my view controller

Comment: your solution absolutely right it would work. But i tried this way i don't whether its correct or not?

Comment: Check that you have the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` properties connected in the storyboard. If so, in `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` function you should be able to check that `userTable.delegate` == `self`. Same for `userTable.dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this line, Your have a table view in the storyboard and taken outlet in viewcontroller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var userTable: UserTable!
```

So you don't need to do this like that:

```
let user = UserTable()
```

You have to give delegate like this:

```
userTable.userdelegate? = self
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried like you said its not working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're instantiating the table view from a storyboard, so you're not setting the delegate on the correct instance of UserTable (and the delegate method is never called because the delegate is nil).

In the view controller change

```
user.userdelegate? = self
```

to

```
userTable.userdelegate? = self
```

Comment: i did like this but no luck

Answer (score -1):

For mine it is working fine with the below scenario. Kindly check with that one.

**UserTable**

```
@objc protocol contactSelectionDelegate: class {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
}

weak var userdelegate: contactSelectionDelegate?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

}

extension ViewController: contactSelectionDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // YOU CAN GET THE ALL THE STUFFS WHICH IS USER SELECTED IN THE TABLE VIEW
    }
}
```

Comment: am getting error in this line         delegate?.tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)